# Reference Display/Editor Templates Across Area Projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application with 2 areas which are seperate projects referenced from the main application. Both the area projects sit with the Areas directory of the main application. I was wondering if i can call DisplayTemplates from one area in another.

For example i have added the following template in the ~/Areas/Area1/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Test.cshtml file:

```
@model string
Test Display Template
```

Now within a view in the Area2 project i say:

```
@Html.Display("Test", "~/Areas/Area1/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Test.cshtml")
```

But it doesn't display anything. I was wondering if someone could let me know if this is possible and what i am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to share templates across Areas, place the template in the root View directory.

Instead of;

```
/Areas/Area1/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Test.cshtml
```

Place it here;

```
/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Test.cshtml
```

Also, the second argument of your Display helper method call;

```
@Html.Display("Test", "~/Areas/Area1/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Test.cshtml")
```

Should be this;

```
@Html.Display("Test", "Test")
```

As the second argument is your template name.
The MVC view engine will track down the template on name, not directory. This is a cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks but i like the idea of packaging the templates up into their own project.

Comment: Are those Area projects MVC Website projects?

Comment: MVC 3 really doesn't handle what your trying to accomplish well. Try looking into MVCContrib and protable areas maybe. They also have a VS project template as well. http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2010/04/07/mvccontrib-portable-area-visual-studio-project-template/

Comment: After further research i'll mark this as the answer but the solution was to use either the MVCContrib's Portable Areas (mentioned above) or with Razor Generator. Hope this helps.